# How to successfully decouple these classes

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I wasn't sure of the best name for this thread, but I'm trying to refactor some code and remove some decoupling. I am forced to use Visual Studio 2005 C++ without boost, don't ask... (So not c++11, or newer)

I have a protocol that receives messages, and the protocol contains a parser and processor. Parser extracts the information out of the message, and populates a structure. The structure is then passed into the processor to take further action on it.

```
class Protocol
{
    Parser parser;
    Processor processor;

public:
    Protocol() : parser(processor)
    {

    }

    handleMessage(Message& message)
    {
        ParsedData parsedData;
        parser.parse(message, parsedData);
    }
}

class Parser
{
    Processor processor;

public:
    Parser()
    {

    }

    Parser(Processor& p) : processor(p)
    {
    }

    parse(Message& message, ParsedData& parsedData)
    {
        if(message.type == "whatever")
        {
            parseLevel2(message.message, parsedData);
        }
        //else if Other message types
    }

    parseLevel2(MessageLevel2& message, ParsedData& parsedData)
    {
        //Keep going down the rabbit hole, but for simplicity it ends here
        parsedData.blah = "some data";
        processor.ProcessBlahMessage(parsedData);
    }
}

class Processor
{
public:
    Processor()
    {
    }

    ProcessBlahMessage(ParsedData& parsedData)
    {
        //Do logic
    }
}
```

I was hoping to strip the Processor from the Parser so it became more like this...

```
class Protocol
{
    Parser parser;
    Processor processor;

public:
    Protocol() : parser(processor)
    {

    }

    handleMessage(Message& message)
    {
        ParsedData parsedData;
        parser.parse(message, parsedData); //This will not call the processor from within it
        processor.process(parsedData);  //This is the new 

    }
}
```

The only issue that is preventing me from doing this is I will have to have a bunch of if statements in the process method.

```
process(ParsedData& parsedData)
{
    if(parsedData.type == "blah")
    {
        ProcessBlahMessage()
    }
    else if(parsedData.type == "grah")
    {
        ProcessGrahMessage()
    }
    //etc...
}
```

My question is how do I avoid all those if statements where I'm essentially just parsing it again? If I give the parsedData a function pointer, or lambda then I'm still going to need a reference to the processor in the parser.

Comment: Is there a common pattern of processing messages? If so, then you can create base class `MessageData`, and then for each message type create its own derived class for data, for example `BlahMessageData`, `GrahMessageData`. After this your parse method will return `MessageData`, which working like a [FactoryMethod](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method). And then `MessageData` will be processed in common way without if statements:)

Comment: @Taztingo I may be wrong but regardless of whether you *Strip* the `Processor` from the `Parser`, you are still stuck with the `if` conditions. What does the *Stripping* have to do with anything?. Also, what do you really mean by *This will not call*? You still need to parse the data don't you?

Comment: @Cking The comment got cut off. It was meant to say this will not call processor manually. I will update it, and hopefully it doesn't get cut off again. The purpose of the question is how to strip it, and how to remove the if statements from the processor.

Comment: @MrPisarik That's a great idea; I was just hoping to not have to create a class for each type of message. I think I may create an unordered_map that you can register callbacks with.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
1) in your parsed data instead of .blah and .grah store `vector<void*>`
2) assuming create new blah object ( or whatever message type is) and put pointer to it into vector (using type as index).
3) in your processor store vector of handlers. pass into processor type along with parsed data, so you can call correct handler for correct pointer
4) in your handler cast void* to blah* (or whatever real type is)

Comment: This is similar to what i was thinking, except with an unordered_map. Good idea.